# How to localize a WP8 class library?

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, windows-phone-8, class-library

I'm trying to use resource files (.resx) in a class library. I'm having trouble using these resources in my library's XAML files because libraries do not come with an App.xaml file. So I can not do:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPLocalization" x:Key="LocalizedStrings" />
</Application.Resources>
```

How do I go about localizing a self-contained WP8 library/assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but it's rather a work around.


The solution is not to try to localize your controls from XAML, but instead from your behind code.


For example, you define a `Button` in XAML as follows:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" />
```

And then in your partial `class` behind you set the content of the button programatically as follows:

```
MyButton.Content = MyLocalizedStrings.Hello;
```

Of course, in this example you would have a resource file called "MyLocalizedStrings.resx" in your project with a string named "Hello" in it.


This approach solves the problem. The only down side is that you won't be able to see a preview of the localized XAML in the Visual Studio XAML window.